# How to embed a UISearchResultsController View in an existing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, search

I'm creating an iOS 9.3 app using Swift and Xcode 7.3.

It displays a list of food categories (table view). Each category contains food items (collection view). Each item has a simple detail page. This view hierarchy is managed by one navigation controller.

I implemented a global (category-agnostic) food item search bar using UISearchController. The search bar is visible in the category view which, however, uses my food item view to display the results. (The results are items, not categories).

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let ficId = "FoodItemsCollectionControllerId"
let fic = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(ficId)
    as! FoodItemsCollectionController

searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: dic)
fic.searchController = searchController
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = fic
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Problem: Whenever I search for an item and click on it, the food item detail view segue cannot be pushed as the item view is not embedded into my navigation controller. I can present the view modally, with no navigation bar (and no way to go back). I could implement a back button by hand, but I'd like an elegant navigation controller solution.

Tried: Pushing, adding and setting the item view controller(s) manually onto the navigation controller. However, it seems to get ignored whenever I set searchResultsController to it when constructing a UISearchController.

```
navigationController?.addChildViewController(fic)
navigationController?.pushViewController(fic, animated: true)
navigationController?.viewControllers = [fic, self]
```

Idea: Use

```
searchController.presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(*, presentingViewController: *, sourceViewController: *)
```

I didn't find good documentation and didn't manage to avoid instance-selector errors at runtime though.

Comment: It hasn't been that long since you posed this question but have you found a solution yet? I've actually run into a similar issue. My table view controller of non-filtered items is embedded within a navigation controller (all done within storyboards). Similar to how you've done I create my search controller programmatically. Unsure of where in the view hierarchy the search controller is inserted. It isn't in the existing nav con!

Comment: @Pouria I've just managed to work around the problem by doing the following in the detail view controller:

`override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {`
`(parentViewController?.parentViewController as? UISearchController)?.searchBar.hidden = true`
`}`
and
`override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {`
`(parentViewController?.parentViewController as? UISearchController)?.searchBar.hidden = false`
`}`

The flaw is that the search bar is not being nicely pushed to the side and is not nicely sliding in from the side on transition.